# what is a good stack for software as a service (SAAS) application?

Tags: platforms, software-as-a-service

We will be engaging large corporations to help them run various types of analysis, mostly code analysis of their applications.  The storage requirements will likely be modest, hundreds of MB per client.

My question is mostly aimed at finding the stack with existing frameworks, best practices and a community which will allow a rapid development process.

I am comfortable with the .Net environment and am leaning towards Azure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh and can someone with enough credits add the tag SaaS please?

Comment: You really need to provide more details. What (specific) kinds of analysis? What are the storage requirements?

Answer (score 3):

We've been running a SaaS for enterprise customers on .NET and our own servers. Everybody seems to be happy.

If you communicate the idea of SaaS to the customer properly, they won't care what it's running on and where.